# RxJS type issue in subscribe for pipeable operators

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5, tslint, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am trying to use RxJS pipeable operators in my angular project. I have an implementation as below.

```
// Service Method
public getItems(params: Object = {}): Observable<JsendResponse> {
    return this.apiService.get('v1/url', params);
}

// JsendResponse interface
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

export interface JsendResponse extends Response {
    data: any;
    message: string;
    status: number;
}

// Component call
this.service
    .getItems({})
    .finally(() => this.loading = false)
    .subscribe(
         response => this.actions = response.data,
         error => this.errors = error
    );
```

In the above example, I am getting the `response` typed correctly with `JsendResponse` type. But when I use `pipe` operator, the `response` is not typed correctly and my IDE is telling that `TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type {}`.

```
this.service
    .getItems({})
    .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.loading = false)
    )
    .subscribe(
        response => this.actions = response.data,
        error => this.errors = error
    );
```

What could be the reason? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried in my pc, I'm not getting any error. Which version of rxjs you're using ?

Comment: RxJS 5.5.6 I am using. My compilation is successful but the autosuggestion of object properties is not working in my IDE which was not the case before.

Comment: are you using vscode? I don't see any suggestion issue.